# Look up information in a json string using Python

Tags: python, json, google-geocoding-api

I tried to find the latitude and longitude of an address through Google Geocoding API.

I got the json string using the following code:

```
address = "the Empire State Building" 
api_key = " " #not shown here
url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=%s&key=%s" % (address,api_key) 
response = requests.get(url) 
response_data = response.json()
```

The dictionary `response_data` is shown as follows.

```
{'results': [{'address_components': [{'long_name': '20',
     'short_name': '20',
     'types': ['street_number']},
    {'long_name': 'West 34th Street',
     'short_name': 'W 34th St',
     'types': ['route']},
    {'long_name': 'Manhattan',
     'short_name': 'Manhattan',
     'types': ['political', 'sublocality', 'sublocality_level_1']},
    {'long_name': 'New York',
     'short_name': 'New York',
     'types': ['locality', 'political']},
    {'long_name': 'New York County',
     'short_name': 'New York County',
     'types': ['administrative_area_level_2', 'political']},
    {'long_name': 'New York',
     'short_name': 'NY',
     'types': ['administrative_area_level_1', 'political']},
    {'long_name': 'United States',
     'short_name': 'US',
     'types': ['country', 'political']},
    {'long_name': '10001', 'short_name': '10001', 'types': ['postal_code']}],
   'formatted_address': '20 W 34th St, New York, NY 10001, USA',
   'geometry': {'location': {'lat': 40.7484405, 'lng': -73.98566439999999},
    'location_type': 'ROOFTOP',
    'viewport': {'northeast': {'lat': 40.7497894802915,
      'lng': -73.98431541970848},
     'southwest': {'lat': 40.7470915197085, 'lng': -73.98701338029149}}},
   'place_id': 'ChIJaXQRs6lZwokRY6EFpJnhNNE',
   'plus_code': {'compound_code': 'P2X7+9P New York, NY, USA',
    'global_code': '87G8P2X7+9P'},
   'types': ['establishment',
    'museum',
    'point_of_interest',
    'tourist_attraction']}],
 'status': 'OK'}
```

What next steps should I do to get the latitude and longitude of that address?

Answer (score 0):

When you run `print(type(response_data))` it returns `dict`?

If it is of the `dict` class, you can use `dict` methods....
Unfortunately, the values you want are in a dictionary in a dictionary in a dictionary in a list in a dictionary.

Long story short, try

```python
latlong =  response_data['results'][0]['geometry']['location']
print(latlong)
```

Longer explanation:
"response_data" is a dict, with 2 keys (your info is stored at 'results').
the value of 'results' is a list,  1 entry (your info is at index 0).
the value at index 0 is a dict, with 6 keys (your info is at key = 'geometry').
the value of 'geometry' is a dict, 3 entries (your info is at key 'location').
the value of 'location' is a dict, 2 entries (your info!!! 'lat', 'lng').